# Linking CodeLite and OpenGL with freeglut on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, codelite

I'm trying to set up CodeLite IDE to use the OpenGL libraries I installed.

The headers are in /usr/include/GL - here's the contents of ls:

```
    freeglut_ext.h  freeglut_std.h  glext.h  gl_mangle.h  glu_mangle.h  glxext.h  glxint.h      glxmd.h     glxtokens.h  freeglut.h      glcorearb.h     gl.h     glu.h        glut.h        glx.h     glx_mangle.h  glxproto.h  internal
```

Here is my simple code snippet:

```
    #include <GL/glut.h>

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        return 0;
    }
```

Finally, here is the output of trying to build the project.

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ cpptest1 - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/brandon/codelite/cpptest/cpptest1'
/usr/bin/g++  -c  "/home/brandon/codelite/cpptest/cpptest1/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -lglut -lGL -lGLU  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I. -I/usr/include/
/usr/bin/g++ -o ./Debug/cpptest1 @"cpptest1.txt" -L. -L/usr/include/GL  -lGL
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/brandon/codelite/cpptest/cpptest1/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `glutInit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cpptest1.mk:76: recipe for target 'Debug/cpptest1' failed
make[1]: *** [Debug/cpptest1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/brandon/codelite/cpptest/cpptest1'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
make: *** [All] Error 2
====2 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Please note that I CAN create a proper binary by using `g++ -o a.out main.cpp -lglut -lGL` from the command line.

I can even use CodeLite to compile the main.cpp file by itself.  I just can't build the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a linker issue, and can be solved as follows:

Project Settings > Linker

Add GL and glut as libraries and point them to your includes (for linux, /usr/include/GL)

[image: Linker Screenshot]

In addition, make sure to add -lglut and -lGL as build flags for the compiler.  It is probably best to add these as Global settings so that you don't break the config when changing between debug and release